# How do I parameterize Java methods and classes

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am using Spock for unit tests.
I want to test Java methods and classes dynamically as in below example. Audit is a Java class. In addition, if possible, I would also like to make Audit class a parameter

```
given:
     Audit audit = GroovyMock()
     expression
     BatchAudit bean = new BatchAudit()

when:
    bean.insertAudit(audit)
then:
    thrown(exc)
where:
    expression | exc
    audit.getFileName() >> {throw new SQLException(new Throwable())} | DataAccessException
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with a few modifications:

1. you need to make `expression` a closure (due to some quirks in the AST, closures can't be the first element in a data table, so it must switch places with `expectedException`)
2. you need to [restore the context](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#rehydrate(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)) for the closure with `expression.rehydrate(null, this, this)`
3. you need to pass the mock instance to the closure as parameter

```
import spock.lang.*

class Audit {
  String getFileName() {
    "foo"
  }
}

class BatchAudit {
  void insertAudit(Audit a) {
    println a.getFileName()
  }
}

class ASpec extends Specification {
  def "test"() {
    given:
    Audit audit = Mock()
    // we need to rehydrate the closure, so that `this` and are correct
    expression.rehydrate(null, this, this).call(audit)
    BatchAudit bean = new BatchAudit()

    when:
    bean.insertAudit(audit)
      
    then:
    Exception e = thrown()
    expectedException.isInstance(e)
      
    where:
    expectedException     | expression
    IllegalStateException | { it.getFileName() >> { throw new IllegalStateException() } }
  }
}
```

Try it out in the [Groovy Webconsole](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?codez=eJxtksFuwjAMhu99il89lWkqd6QhMWmTOGwXXoAsNW20kFSJoUzAu88EKK3EJU2c359_uzHb1gdGbL3-La1ydfmSZdqqGLHYVYZxzIAVB-Nq1MSfxtK32lIxSRdAvvE-l905O9_z3hXr5pG896aCcZECp2BxvVJ3Qitstg6qHPHHzMWqJQ06MLkq4nIwG6MVG-8SpqINcqbIee-sNntys7S9VUzrG76k1cQHplN0BEdUgT0CNX9VUEzghqCtj7tAr4hezoqx5sbENZSroILc-xBIc-LQoQ0Uo7gpe0jhdta-4pJ0XSelVtYWyca1_GBSP6SceHPUDaLiMum65t7JRVYOhzmgAenDvfjjoKlNIyJBcxN8526Ni2HxTlUvKU1cusjKaSpoxJPigWbPs5LqNGg_yZbWUq3simUKD-kJRxge_2TM5xJNzlLrTzNFdpa3cHsP_9LK2jk).